# How do I remove a Facebook Page property from the About Tab using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, attributes, facebook-page

I have successfully set the attributes of my Facebook Page using the Graph API following the documentation for this functionality [at this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#attributes).  For example I am able to set the `general_info` field by sending a post body with the following:

```
access_token=<MY_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>&general_info=This+is+some+general+info.
```

But now I would like to remove the `general_info`.  I assumed that sending a post body with an empty string would remove it

```
access_token=<MY_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>&general_info=
```

but I get back

```
{
    "error":{
        "message":"(#100) Parameters do not match any fields that can be updated",
        "type":"OAuthException",
        "code":100
    }
}
```

I have also tried:

```
access_token=<MY_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>&general_info=None
```

and

```
access_token=<MY_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>&general_info=null
```

But these just set my General Info to 'None' and 'null'.  I also tried sending JSON content so that the `null` would be unambiguous, but the API just seemed to respond as if it couldn't handle JSON at all.

My other thought was that maybe it requires an HTTP DELETE request, but as far as I can tell the Graph API doesn't return any ids for these properties that could be used for the DELETE request.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sending a space.

```
access_token=<MY_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>&general_info=+
```

That might work

Comment: That does seem to work.  I find it pretty strange that if I send an url encoded space character it works, but an empty string give a cryptic error message.  Oh well, Facebook works in mysterious ways.  Thanks!